# Sort array values for a particular slice from 3d DataArray

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray

Summary: Given a 3D array, how I can I slice at two particular co-ordinates and then sort on the VALUES of the 3rd dimension, retaining index information

Preamble:

I am trying to compare the cost of shopping baskets for customers buying a combination of apples and bananas. I know our competitors unit costs for these fruits, and depending on what cost I choose, I can be cheaper or more expensive. I would like to be able to rank my basket costs for a particular combination (e.g. 3 apples and 15 bananas) within my competitors.

I've tried to include all the relevant code but the real salient point is at the end.

1) Building a function which takes in a price point for apples and bananas, and returns a grid of order cost:

```python
apple_range = np.arange(1, 12, 1)
banana_range = np.arange(5, 30, 5)

def order_costs(no_apples, no_bananas, apple_cost=None, banana_cost=None):
    return (no_apples * apple_cost) + (no_bananas * banana_cost)

fv = np.vectorize(order_costs, excluded=['apple_cost', 'banana_costs'])
```

2) My competitors pricing as a dataframe, and then a 3D numpy array with the 'depth' axis used for each competitor

```python
fruit_prices = pd.DataFrame(
    data = [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]],
    index = ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    columns = ['apple_cost', 'banana_cost'],
)

order_costs_dict = {}
for idx, row in fruit_prices.iterrows():
    order_costs_dict[idx] = fv(apple_range[:, np.newaxis], banana_range, **dict(row))
order_costs = np.dstack(list(order_costs_dict.values()))
```

[image]

3) Convert the data into a DataArray

```python
bvs_dataset = xr.Dataset(
    {'order_costs':(['apples', 'bananas', 'supplier'], order_costs)},
    coords = {'apples': (['apples'], apple_range),
             'bananas': (['bananas'], banana_range),
             'supplier': (['supplier'], list(order_costs_dict.keys()))}
)

bvs_array = bvs_dataset.to_array()
```

Now I make my selection, I want to know the costs of ordering 1 apple and 5 bananas

4)

```python
selection = bvs_array.sel(apples=1, bananas=5)
selection
```

[image]

**QUESTION:**

Assuming these results aren't ordered ascending, how can I

1) Sort them according to order_costs, whilst retaining the information in the 'index' (Supplier name, A, B or C)

2) Find the rank of my corresponding order cost e.g. if my order costs 19 then this will return 2.

I have tried the `sortby()` method on my selection but if I pass 'order_costs' as the variable, I receive KeyError. Sorting by 'variable' doesn't seem to have the right effect, although doesn't raise an error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found my answer.

1) Make my selection 1 dimensional

`selection = selection[0]`

2) Reindex by the argsorted variable

`selection = selection[selection.variable.argsort()]`

3) Now selection should be sorted and you have the indicies to look at the `supplier` column too.

I had a look at the indices returned by `argsort()` and they didn't appear to match order_value order, but when I actually used it, it gave me the right answer.